# Real-time audio signal processing using python

Tags: python, audio, signals, real-time, cython

I have been trying to do real-time audio signal processing using 'pyAudio' module in python. What I did was a simple case of reading audio data from microphone and play it via headphones. I tried with the following code(both Python and Cython versions). Thought it works but unfortunately it is stalls and not smooth enough. How can I improve the code so that it will run smoothly. My PC is i7, 8GB RAM.

Python Version

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

RATE    = 16000
CHUNK   = 256
    
p               =   pyaudio.PyAudio()

player = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, output=True, 
frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

for i in range(int(20*RATE/CHUNK)): #do this for 10 seconds
    player.write(np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16))
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Cython Version

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

cdef int RATE   = 16000
cdef int CHUNK  = 1024
cdef int i      
p               =   pyaudio.PyAudio()

player = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

for i in range(500): #do this for 10 seconds
    player.write(np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16))
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "stalls" and what you expect. There is nothing to be gained by using cython -there are no python calculations, everything is done by c code inside of libraries. You call it real-time, but use blocking IO - how should it work? Use the nonblocking version https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#example-callback-mode-audio-i-o

Comment: By 'stalls', I meant  the audio breaks in between. How does blocking mode and non blocking differ?, Thank you for the link.

Comment: In your case "blocking" means, when it plays it does not record and when it records it does not play

Comment: @ead , while non-blocking can be used to wire input (microphone) to output (headset/speaker) directly, you cant do any processing on the audio as you have not access/control on it. For any mid-stream processing OP will need to use blocking version (which he is using).

Comment: @SAJIL C K, pls check my answer for solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't multithread the application?  All the python real time audio processing examples I've seen have used multithreading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are missing `CHUNK` as second argument to `player.write` call.

```
player.write(np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16),CHUNK)
```

Also, not sure if its formatting error. But `player.write` needs to be tabbed into `for` loop

And per [pyaudio site](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) you need to have `RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS` and not `RECORD *RATE/CHUNK` as `python` executes `*` multiplication before `/` division.

```
for i in range(int(20*RATE/CHUNK)): #do this for 10 seconds
    player.write(np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16),CHUNK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Finally, you may want to increase `rate` to `44100` , `CHUNK` to `1024` and `CHANNEL` to `2` for better fidelity.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your suggestions. After including 'CHUNK' as argument to 'player' object, it was way better, but still getting the error 'ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred'. 
I did a bit of research and found out it was something related to buffer size. So I experimented with the 'CHUNK' size and found out  128 is a good value. It still get the same error but only for the first few seconds after that it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried to up-vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: It is customary to select answer on SO if it helps you towards your question. It helps close the loop and It also adds points to your account. See here on how to accept answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Don’t need to. If u see so stats , many questions are  not resolved even though valid answers are provided.  This crates “noise” and skews stats.  I was also guiding newcomers. Hope that helps.

Comment: A lot of online examples, including other questions, appear to be missing the argument `CHUNK` from `write()` - adding this solved my issue. I was getting weird / buzzy sound. Not same issue as question OP

Answer (score 8):

The code below will take the default input device, and output what's recorded into the default output device.

```
import PyAudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    # using Numpy to convert to array for processing
    # audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                output=True,
                input=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(20)
    stream.stop_stream()
    print("Stream is stopped")

stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

This will run for 20 seconds and stop. The method callback is where you can process the signal :
`audio_data = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)`

`return in_data` is where you send back post-processed data to the output device.

Note chunk has a default argument of 1024 as noted in the PyAudio docs:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.open

Answer (score 5):

I am working on a similar project. I modified your code and the stalls now are gone. The bigger the chunk the bigger the delay. That is why I kept it low.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 2**5
RATE = 44100
LEN = 10

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
player = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


for i in range(int(LEN*RATE/CHUNK)): #go for a LEN seconds
    data = np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16)
    player.write(data,CHUNK)


stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```